# Proving a limit using another limit

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $f(x)$ be a functions that's defined at some neighbourhood of $0$

$$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x} = 3$$

> Prove that:
>   $$
> \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(3x)}{\ln(1+4x)} = 2.25
> $$

I really don't know what to in order to convert the given limit $$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x} = 3$$

and use it in the expression. I know I can do:

$$
\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(3x)}{3x}\frac{3x}{\ln(1+4x)}
$$

But how will that help me?

Comment: You could use a substitution to find the limit of the first factor and (shudder) L'Hôpital for the second.

Comment: I'm not allowed to use L'Hopital yet :\, but how will I substitute? it's $f(3x)$, not $f(x)$

Comment: $3x\rightarrow0$ if $x\rightarrow0$. You have $3x$ downstairs too. Setting $u=3x$, the limit is $\lim_{u\rightarrow0} {f(u)\over u}$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may write, as $x$ is near $0$, $x\neq0$,
$$
\frac{f(3x)}{\ln(1+4x)} =\frac{f(3x)}{3x}\frac{3x}{\ln(1+4x)}=\frac{f(3x)}{3x}\frac{4x}{\ln(1+4x)} \frac{3}{4}
$$
then use
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(3x)}{3x} = 3
$$
and
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\ln(1+4x)}{4x}= \lim_{u \to 0} \frac{\ln(1+u)}{u}=1
$$
to conclude that the desired limit is $\displaystyle \frac{3\times 3}{4} =\frac94=2.25.$

Answer (score 6):

You're on the correct way:

$$
\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(3x)}{3x}\frac{3x}{\ln(1+4x)}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(3x)}{3x}\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{3x}{\ln(1+4x)}=\lim_{y \to 0}\frac{f(y)}{y}\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{3x}{4x}=3\times \frac34=\frac94
$$

Comment: How did you get rid of the $ln$ ?

Comment: I used the Taylor expansion 
$$\ln(1+4x)\sim_0 4x$$
and if you don't allowed to use it you can use the L'hôpital's rule.